# Extracting text from a PDF and getting the coordinates of an embedded image

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext

I need to extract text from a pdf document and I am using the iTextSharp library to do so. The issue is that the image has text on it which is not part of the image. I have been looking to find a way to get the coordinates of the image as there are annotations on the image being included in the text extraction:

e.g.
[image]

Results in the extraction:

**Some text...
Text
Text
More Text..**

However, the text in the image is irrelevant and needs to be ignored to give the output:

**Some text...
More text...**

Another issue is that there are multiple pages with this issue with images all being different sizes, however, all the text is always within the image bounds which is why if I have a way of determining the height and x, y coordinates of the image relative to the page I can extract the necessary data.

Currently, I need to just get the text but I will also need to extract the images at a later date.

Comment: `RenderListener` instances (like text extraction strategies) are not only informed about text elements but also about bitmap images. Thus, you merely need to extend your text extraction strategy of choice to listen to those image events, store the image locations and dimensions, and at the end of page processing remove those text chunks inside image areas.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look now

Comment: @mkl I think the issue is the pdf I am using uses vectors - is this an issue, everywhere I have read indicates that it won't work with vectors? I tried to implement a IRenderListener object that stores the image width and height but it errors when run. with the error 'The color space is not supproted'

Comment: For vector graphics you need the `IExtRenderListener`. But beware, the image is not a single event there but you get each and every stroke or curve separately (that's pdf for you), so the image area is not so well defined. If there indeed is something like the blue rectangle frame around it, you may be in luck, otherwise some heuristics may become necessary.

Comment: *'The color space is not supproted'* - PDF has its own very flexible bitmap format. If there are images in that format, Itext tries to export them to a more usual format (like PNG) but due to the flexibility of the pdf bitmap format, that sometimes is not possible, in particular not losslessly. In such situations you get such an error message.

Comment: @mkl Ok, I think the other issue is the PDF's are protected. Will I still be able to extract the data this way or is it impossible. Ahh ok, that makes sense.

Comment: The protection usually should not be an issue. If need be, there is a `PdfReader` flag to override protection restriction. Please only use it if you are indeed entitled to extract the data.

Comment: @mkl yeah - its for a college project and its the exam board material